# Firefox dev tools paint flashing view: what do the different colours represent?

Tags: firefox, repaint, firefox-developer-tools

When viewing paint flashing with Firefox developer tools, many different colored rectangles appear on the page. I have searched online for an explanation of what those colors mean and have found nothing, even on [the relevant MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Paint_Flashing_Tool).

What do the different colors represent?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors themselves don't have a special meaning. They differ to make it easier to spot, which parts of the page got repainted.

That those colors are random can easily be seen by hovering over a scrollbar within the page after enabling paint flashing. Everytime you hover it it will get another color.